# How do I get httrack to save files with their original names rather than index****.html?

Tags: html, web-scraping, wget, httrack

I'm following the HTTrack docs example here: http://httrack.kauler.com/help/User-defined_structure

The site I need to scrape has URLs in this structure:

> `https://www.example.com/index.php?HelpTopics`
>
> `https://www.example.com/index.php?MoreHelp`
>
> etc.

With HTTrack, I want to download the site save the files in the format

> `HelpTopics.html` `MoreHelp.html` etc.

I'm using this on the command line modified from the docs linked above:

`httrack "https://www.example.com" %n%[index.php?:-:::].%t`

but I still get all files saved as `index2b26.html` and `index2de7.html` etc.

What am I doing wrong with the HTTrack options? Is this breaking because there are no file extensions on the original site `example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it's much easier to use `wget` to save file with their original names. This does it:

`wget --mirror -p --convert-links --content-disposition --trust-server-names -P examplefolder http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

From the link, the `param` in `%[param:before:after:empty:notfound]` is supposed to be a variable in a GET query. Since your URL does not have a variable, I think the default filename would've been right.